# Function for estimation of Gaussian Mixture Model with fixed means in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gmm

Is there a function for estimation of GMM model with fixed means? So far I have found only `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` which however takes only initial means, but AFAIK can not fix the means. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (by looking at the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910446/sklearn-gaussian-mixture-lock-parameters)) it is not possible to used fixed means for the GMM. You can only provide values for the initial guesses, but for fixed values you would have to change the code.

A question there was

> So it's not possible to force, or restrict the parameters in certain ranges, instead of just initial guesses?

With the answer:

> Not without changing the code. As this defeats the whole EM-approach
> in my opinion! (but i would not consider myself an expert there).